# Does HighStock has tree kind of charts available?

Tags: highcharts

Does HighStock has tree kind of charts available in free or license version?
We are using HighStock library to draw timeline charts, however could not find any examples of tree/graph type of visualization.
Something similar to 'yFiles for HTML'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tree graph is not available, but you can vote for this suggestion in our uservoice http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general?query=tree Obviously you can try to use scatter chart with customised markers.

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/scatter